# Relationships Search other than via Advanced Search?

Tags: search, search-results, custom-search, search-builder

Is there an option to find the related contacts (e.g. employee of) of an organization other than with the advanced search?

We seem to have an error/bug in our advanced search. It shows the correct results on the initial search, but when creating and saving the smart group, the settings for the advanced search seem to reset.

The search builder doesn’t allow to search for relationships. The relationship report doesn’t allow to save the results in a smart group.

Is there any other option I can’t think of right now?

What are trying to do is to get all related contacts (employee of) of our organization members in one smart group.

Comment: It's likely that the bug you're experiencing is due to an older version of CiviCRM.  What is your CiviCRM version?  It's probably best to resolve the underlying issue resolved.

Comment: Thanks Jon. We went down your suggested pass. We had debugged the issue and found the reason for our problem. It was a caching issue. Caching was enabled for CiviCRM, which messed up the search result. We weren't able to save to smart groups, nor export contacts properly. Since we changed the cache setting in .htaccess to only cache css and images, things work as expected again.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a go on Demo

"This smart group will stay up-to-date with all contacts who meet the search criteria.

Employee of

Relationship - Active and Current"

I don't know if it will still be there by the time you get to look at it. http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?reset=1&force=1&ssID=1

Comment: Thanks Peter. I couldn't access it anymore, but what I am seeing from the URL is, that you used the advanced search for getting to the "Employee of" results. The Advanced Search does work great for that, but we have a current bug in OUR system, that doesn't allow me to save the results in a smart group. It allows me to search for it and I see the results which are correctly displayed, but once saving them in a smart group, the search criterias are reset and thus the contacts in the smart group are not correct. I am now looking for a way to find the "Employees of" without using advanced search.

Comment: If you are on Drupal then a Views display should give this to you very easily.